# java.lang.NullPointerException at java.net.URLEncoder.encode at com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addValuesToParameter

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, url-encoding

I am trying to run jsf application using netbeans and having this exception of NullPointerException in URLEncode. I think some problems with Servlet but i dont know how to fix it Sources : [https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-application-petstore-ee6](https://github.com/agoncal/agoncal-application-petstore-ee6][1])

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:204)
        at com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addValuesToParameter(UrlBuilder.java:318)
        at com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addParameters(UrlBuilder.java:127)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.encodeBookmarkableURL(ExternalContextImpl.java:1054)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(MultiViewHandler.java:407)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getBookmarkableURL(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:272)
        at org.jboss.weld.jsf.ConversationAwareViewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(ConversationAwareViewHandler.java:132)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getEncodedTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:194)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.renderAsActive(OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.java:158)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.java:96)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:204)
        at com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addValuesToParameter(UrlBuilder.java:318)
        at com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addParameters(UrlBuilder.java:127)
        at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.encodeBookmarkableURL(ExternalContextImpl.java:1054)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(MultiViewHandler.java:407)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getBookmarkableURL(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:272)
        at org.jboss.weld.jsf.ConversationAwareViewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(ConversationAwareViewHandler.java:132)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getEncodedTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:194)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.renderAsActive(OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.java:158)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.java:96)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
        at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It comes when i go to index.xhtml

Comment: @lxmkv , is the file's extension mistyped here : `<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>` ? it should be `index.xhtml`.

Comment: @Omar: that would have produced a very different problem.

Answer (score 20):

Read the stack trace from bottom to top and pick the relevant lines to understand the flow.

```
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
```

So, `FacesServlet` is invoked and servicing the request.

---

```
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120
```

So, render response phase is executed.

---

```
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
```

So a Facelets (XHTML) file will be rendered.

---

```
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(OutcomeTargetLinkRenderer.java:96)
```

So, a `<h:link>` is being rendered.

---

```
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getEncodedTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:194)
```

So, it needs to render the target URL.

---

```
    at com.sun.faces.context.UrlBuilder.addParameters(UrlBuilder.java:127)
```

So, the link has `<f:param>` values which need to be added to target URL.

---

```
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:204)
```

And they need to be URL encoded.

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

However, the `value` of a `<f:param>` of a `<h:link>` appears to be `null`.

I think you get it now?

Answer (score 4):

I got such issue when migrated from GlassFish 4.0 (NetBeans 7) to GlassFish 4.1 (NetBeans 8). Exactly the reason is that `<f:param>` should have not null value. In GlassFish 4.0 it was not a problem and just parameter was not added to generated link. But GlassFish 4.1 has different jsf implementation which fails with `NullPointerException` whenever value in `<f:param>` is null.

As a fix I did next. Instead of `<f:param value="#{myBean.field}"/>`
I used `<f:param value="#{not empty myBean.field ? myBean.field : ''}"/>`
And using only property `rendered` will not help.
Or it could be rounded with `<c:if>` like:

```
<c:if test="#{not empty myBean.field}">
    <f:param value="#{myBean.field}"/>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using the disable parameter for the f:param. This code is working on Payara 5 (based on Glassfish).

```
<h:link outcome="nextpage" value="click here">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{myBean.id}" disable="#{empty myBean.id}"/>
</h:link>
```

The parameter "id" will not be added to the URL if it is null or empty neither be added to the outcome.

If the link doesn't make sense when the parameter is empty, you can also disable the entire link and it will turn into regular text (), note the parameter for the h:link is disabled instead of disable:

```
<h:link outcome="nextpage" value="click here" disabled="#{empty myBean.id}">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{myBean.id}"/>
</h:link>
```

Both solutions avoid the NullPointerException on URLEncoder.encode.